# Send/Receive WiFi traffic data

Tags: c#, .net, wifi

Is it possible to monitor WiFi traffic and send data myself? My goal is to learn how to monitor probe requests, send deauth packets, and other operations similar to AirCrack and the other libraries found on the BackTrack os flavor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a tough time doing what you want to do in a Windows environment. If you poke around the Aircrack site a bit you'll see that the Windows version is pretty useless in comparison to its Linux counterpart, in large part due to the open source driver availability in Linux and the lack thereof in Windows. You can definitely packet sniff etc. ( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET ) but you won't get the robustness that you can get out of a similar application in Linux.

Comment: I did see that its hard on Windows and I never thought about it. Thanks for explaining it and posting a link!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about sending just random radio signals, but you can certainly monitor the traffic and data. Here is an [article which describes how to do it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4217/Packet-Sniffing-with-Winpcap-Functions-Ported-to-a).

Comment: Don't you think this is a comment, not an answer?

Answer (score 1):

AirPcap from Riverbed.  USB adapter that can run in monitor mode and has an API for channel switching and more, and you can send Wi-Fi frames if you buy the right adapter. Wireshark has builtin support too.  The Alfa cards are a good choice, but only for 'nix